# JUnit5: Before and After Suite method invocation

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

I've spent a few days trying to find out a solution, so I know all the basic answers

> I've read the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/), and I know, that @BeforeClass/@AfterClass is replaced with @BeforeAll/@AfterAll, @RunWith no longer exists; superseded by @ExtendWith
>  I've read all the topics here on the stackoverflow (removed links, since stackoverflow pretends it's a spam:(

I used to run some JUnit4 tests in the suites. Each Suite class *Suite1.class, Suite2.class* had several *@Test* methods and *@BeforeClass/@AfterClass* were running **exactly** before/after **all** the testing methods.

```
@RunWith(StopOnFailureSuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        Test1.class,
        Test2.class
})

public class TSuite_20 {
    private static final byte SUITE_NUMBER = 20;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        //some logic for suite setup
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
        //some logic for teardown
    }
}
```

As I wanted to use @ParameterizedTests I need to migrate to JUnit5.
And suddenly I realised, that exact the same behaviour, that used to be in JUnit4 is no more achievable.
[run some custom setup code; run several test classes, which may contain several @Test methods; run some custom tear down code];

Does anybody know (better with examples) an approach to make it with JUnit 5?

**Option 1**
This code will never execute `BeforeAfterSuite#beforeAll` and `BeforeAfterSuite#afterAll`

```
@ExtendWith(BeforeAfterSuite.class)
@Suite
@SelectClasses({
        Test1.class,
        Test2.class
})
public class TSuite_20 {
    public static final byte SUITE_NUMBER = 20;
}

public class BeforeAfterSuite implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback
/*,TestInstancePreConstructCallback, BeforeTestExecutionCallback, 
AfterTestExecutionCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource*/ {
    private static boolean started = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            //before stuff
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        //after all;
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
I was just curious, how will JUnit treat suite class if I put a test method into it...
This code will execute `BeforeAfterSuite#beforeAll` and `BeforeAfterSuite#afterAll` **once**, before and after TSuite_20#test

```
@ExtendWith(BeforeAfterSuite.class)
@Suite
@SelectClasses({
        Test1.class,
        Test2.class
})
public class TSuite_20 {
    public static final byte SUITE_NUMBER = 20;
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

**Option 3**
We also can apply `@ExtendWith(BeforeAfterSuite.class)` per Test class which will results in a `BeforeAfterSuite#beforeAll` and `BeforeAfterSuite#afterAll` per Test class. (in this example - **2 times**).

```
@ExtendWith(BeforeAfterSuite.class)
public class Test1 {
    
    @Test
    public void test11() {
    }
    @Test
    public void test12() {
    }
}

@ExtendWith(BeforeAfterSuite.class)
public class Test2 {
    
    @Test
    public void test21() {
    }
    @Test
    public void test22() {
    }
}
```

**Option 4**
I also give a shot for

- a Suite class without `@ExtendWith()` and `@BeforeAll + @AfterAll`; (as expected nothing happened)`
- a Suite class without `@ExtendWith()` and `@BeforeAll + @Test + @AfterAll`; (as expected single execution of BeforeAll/AfterAll for the specific Suite class)`

**Option 5**
Listeners were my last hope to achieve the desired behaviour.
I've created my own impl for LauncherSessionListener, just because I've thought it will allow me to execute smth exactly before tests start.

```
public class BeforeAfterSuiteLauncher implements LauncherSessionListener {
    private static boolean started = false;
    @Override
    public void launcherSessionOpened(LauncherSession session) {
        if (!started) {
            started = true;
            //before all
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void launcherSessionClosed(LauncherSession session) {
        //after all
    }
}
```

And I've added also some default impl CompositeLauncherSessionListener

Packages structure screenshot to show Java SPI configuration: [LauncherSessionListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie69r.png)

For TestExecutionListener I've added two default impls, just to catch at least one Listener:

```
org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.LoggingListener
org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.SummaryGeneratingListener
```

and one custom

```
public class BeforeAfterExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan) {
        //before all
    }

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {
        //after all
    }
}
```

Packages structure screenshot to show Java SPI configuration:[TestExecutionListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvDZu.png)

And only SummaryGeneratingListener was triggered!

What am I doing wrong? Why my BeforeAfterExecutionListener impl was not loaded and triggered?

P.S. All of the above code was executed under Intellij Idea 2021.1.3 Ultimate Edition

```
java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)
```

here is intelliJs command:

```
C:\Tools\jdk\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:61280,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1705687115.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 com.testdirectly.application.testcase.TSuite_20
```

Which results in [JUnit5IdeaTestRunner](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/junit5_rt/src/com/intellij/junit5/JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java)

My gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
        //JUnit platform
        // to group tests by package, by class name, by class name pattern, etc (use @Suite, @SelectClasses) :junit-platform-suite-api:1.9.2
        // and to filter/discover and run them         (SuiteLauncher, SuiteTestEngine, SuiteTestDescriptor) :junit-suite-engine:1.9.2
        testImplementation "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:1.9.2"
        //Launcher, engine discovery
        testImplementation "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.9.2"//to run tests

        //JUnit Jupiter
        //to use assertions and so on
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2"
        //to use @ParameterizedTest
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.2"
        //Jupiter engine to run junit5 tests (JupiterTestEngine, Extensions, etc)
        testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

Option 5 works if you tweak it slightly (see below).

### Long answer

Options 1 and 2 do not work because `@ExtendWith` is a Jupiter extension mechanism whereas `@Suite` triggers an engine of its own.
Test engines do not combine on the JUnit platform.

The same goes for option 4 since `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` are Jupiter annotations.

#### Making Option 5 Work

First of all I'd suggest to use `TestExecutionListener` instead of `LauncherSessionListener` because the latter is still experimental.

Thus we have

```java
package my.project.suites;

import org.junit.platform.launcher.*;

public class BeforeAfterSuiteListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan) {
        System.out.println("before all");
    }

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {
        System.out.println("after all");
    }
}
```

The missing thing is now that you'll have to register `BeforeAfterSuiteListener` globally.
In classpath-based Java you do that through a resource file
`META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener`:

```
my.project.suites.BeforeAfterSuiteListener
```

Now `before all` and `after all` should show up in your output exactly once per test run.

Comment: Thank you for your time, sir. I do not understand your explanation for Options 1 and 2. I'm not sure if `@Suite` triggers any engine, it looks more as a way to group by tests. I've added Option 2 just to make sure that `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` are designed to be used at class level, not suite. Which is important and not reflected in the documentation.
Sorry, I can see any difference between yours and mine implementations of the Option5.

Comment: The difference is the registration through Java’s service provider mechanism. It works in the example I set up locally. If it doesn’t in your setup something else is going on and you’d have to provide all the missing details like full Gradle file and directory structure.

Comment: thank you, sir! I do not know where exactly my problem is hidden, but when I've exctracted minimum reproducible project with a single gradle module it worked out as expected. (As a newcommer I Do not have enough reputation to up vote)

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I implemented it this way for the finalization of the Suite.
Didn't try the init as I didn't need it, but it should work the same way.
Not sure this code works for parallels tests though.

```java
@SelectClasses({
      Test1.class,
      Test2.class,
      Test3.class
      MySuite.FinalizeSuite.class
    })
public class MySuite
{
    public static class FinalizeSuite
    {
        @Test
        public void nothing()
        {}
        @AfterAll
        public static void tearDown()
        {
            //my suite finalization code
        }       
    }
    
}
```

I don't really like it as it is a lot of code to replace the Junit4 @BeforeSuite / @AfterSuite, but it is the best compromise I found for a simple solution.

Comment: it might come soon 
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/456